# Slice circular linestring by shortest distance between 2 points

Tags: gis, polygon, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I have a polygon of a farming field. I am dropping 2 Points along the field borders in order to easily measure the distance between those points.

This works great most of the time, but in some situations the sliced line takes "the long way round".

### Question

**How do I slice a linestring in the direction of the shortest distance between the 2 points?**

#### More context

1. First I take a polygon and convert it to a linestring
2. Then I use Turf functions to slice the line at the start and end points

```
import { polygonToLine } from '@turf/polygon-to-line'
import lineSlice from '@turf/line-slice'

const slicedLineString = lineSlice(
    startPoint,
    endPoint,
    polygonToLine(polygonFeature)
)
```

Blank context image of the field:

[image: starting point]

The below image is correct, the shortest distance shown by the black line:

[image: working correctly]

The below image shows the black line measuring in the wrong direction, not the shortest distance/direction between the 2 points.

[image: not working correctky]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

1. Looping through all the coordinates of the linestring, finding the coordinate pair that is furthest from both the start and coordinates
2. Re-order the linestring coordinates so that it starts from this furthest away point

```
const lineString = polygonToLine(JSON.parse(this.parcel.geometry))

// Loop through all coordinates of linestring Feature, find coordinate pair that is furthest from both the start and end coordinates
let furthestDistance = 0
let furthestIndex = 0

for (let i = 0; i < lineString.geometry.coordinates.length; i++) {
    const distanceToStart = distance(lineString.geometry.coordinates[i], this.startCoordinates, {
        units: 'kilometers'
    })

    const distanceToEnd = distance(lineString.geometry.coordinates[i], this.endCoordinates, {
        units: 'kilometers'
    })

    const totalDistance = distanceToStart + distanceToEnd

    if (totalDistance > furthestDistance) {
        furthestDistance = totalDistance
        furthestIndex = i
    }
}

// Re-order linestring geometry coordinates so that the furthest coordinate pair is at the start
const reorderedCoordinates = lineString.geometry.coordinates
    .slice(furthestIndex)
    .concat(lineString.geometry.coordinates.slice(0, furthestIndex))

lineString.geometry.coordinates = reorderedCoordinates

this.slicedLine = lineSlice(this.startCoordinates, this.endCoordinates, lineString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply measure both ways, then take the shorter one:

```
const slicedLineString1 = lineSlice(
    startPoint,
    endPoint,
    polygonToLine(polygonFeature)
)
const slicedLineString2 = lineSlice(
    endPoint,
    startPoint,
    polygonToLine(polygonFeature)
)

const shorter = length(slicedLineString1) < length(slicedLineString2) ? slicedLineString1 : slicedLineString2;
```

Comment: I think the original problem was because of the start/end of the linestring was  between the 2 points. I don't think it's possible to go one way because the line starts at that location so the only path is the long way, which is why in my solution below I move the break/start of the linestring away from where I'm trying to measure to avoid that.